# Can We Execute pywinauto script file from ironpython

Tags: c#, python-3.x, ironpython, pywinauto

I have a python script (a.py) which uses pywinauto.application.

I am running c# code (ironpython) to execute the above file

```
py.ExecuteFile("Path for b.py");
```

but i am getting an exception

> No module named pywinauto.application

Comment: If you can figure out how to install `pywin32` on IronPython, then you have a chance. But as I know, `pywin32` doesn't support IronPython. Technically it's possible to eliminate `pywin32` dependency but it requires plenty of work. We may consider it after other important features like Linux and macOS support. So don't expect it even in 2020. Of course, you always have a workaround to install CPython and run it as external process using `subprocess.Popen`. The same thing applies to Jython. We have not so many requests on IronPython/Jython support hence lower priority.

Comment: Which version of IronPython are you using?